# toyota highlander moonroof stuck open

Tags: toyota, sunroof

2007 toyota moonroof stuck open.
It will move between 100% open and roughly 90% open.
It appears to open slightly farther on drivers side before coming to a stop.
There is a clicking noise once it stops. I can then retract to 100% open ok.

Could anyone provide an idea of how to manually close or fix this?

Comment: Is the clicking noise repetitive as long as you press the button for the moon roof?

Comment: Yes. At about the 90% open, movement stops and the clicking starts as long as button actuated.

Comment: It looks to me that the mechanism, cogs and staff like that are broken and they need replacing. But because I'm no familiar with these parts. I would suggest to have a second opinion for this matter from someone else...

Comment: Did the sunroof lose power prior to malfunctioning?  Either blowing a fuse or if the vehicle battery was disconnected. A bit of searching finds that after losing power, there's a process to reset the zero position.